# How to know if my PC is compatible with VMware Player

Tags: virtualization, vmware, compatibility, vmware-player

**Context:**

I have to run a virtual machine with VMware Player (version 16) on a HP ProLiant ML350 G6 Server. I already had some hardware compatibility problems in the past, so before installing anything I want to be sure that the machine is compatible. [Here](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01713311#N10011) you can find the specs. I think that the most critical component should be the processor, which is a Intel Xeon Processor L5506 (2.13 GHz, 4 MB L3 Cache, 60W, DDR3-800).

I am finding some difficulties to understand if my HW is compatible with my version of VMware player. [From here](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=cpu&productid=22&vcl=true) I can see that my machine should be compatible with:

- ESXi 6.5 U3
- ESXi 6.5 U2
- ESXi 6.5 U1
- ESXi 6.5
- ESXi 6.0 U3
- ESXi 6.0 U2
- ESXi 6.0 U1
- ESXi 6.0

Unfortunately, I am no expert about VMware, so I don't know the link between ESXi and VMware.

**Question:**

How can I know the compatibility of my machine with VMware player, starting from the compatibility with ESXi?

Comment: Are you worried about compatibility with VMWare Player or VMWare ESXi? VMWare Player to my knowledge cannot connect to a ESXi host which isn’t the case for VMWare Workstation or vCenter

Comment: Unfortunately your question just doesn’t have enough information to determine why your asking about VMWare Player but listing server specifications. One typically would install ESXi on that equipment and then manage it with a vCenter appliance or VMWare Workstation on another PC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a table that links the version of ESXi with the hardware version [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2007240).

As of 2021 November:
[image]

Comment: It would be useful if the downvoter explained the reason why this answer is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Any reasonable machine will run VMware Workstation or VMware Player. I have (had also) Workstation on Lenovo X1, X230, M73, M70s (all current right now), Lenovo T61 and machines before.

The item you need to know is if BIOS (UEFI) supports Hardware Virtualization and VT-d.  You need these enabled to run 64-bit guests.

If a machine does not have Hardware Virtualization, then you can only run 32-bit guests.

You also need ample memory, minimally 16 GB.

Your machine is a Server and I did not see it on the Player list. See if you can find the Hardware Virtualization specs for it.

Comment: "Any reasonable machine will run VMware Workstation or VMware Player." are you sure? I tried to run VM Player on another machine, older than the one of the post, but I got a message telling me that the hardware was not compatible, so VMware Player couldn't be launched

Comment: From 2008 forward, all my machines ran VMware and 64-bit guests.  Before that (XP host) my guest machines were 32-bit. Just check specs for hardware virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that can run (any version of) ESXi can run VMWare Player.
The requirements for VMWare Player are a subset of ESXi.
So your Proliant server is fine for that.

But I hope you realize that VMWare Player is an application on top of a normal Operating System. You will have to install Windows or Linux on that Proliant first.